# System variable to the update query of int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-jdbc

I am using a int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter.
I am facing issue with my update statement.I need pass single value ,since I have hard coded that value in RowMapper ,that's why I am receiving 5 values in place of 1.(max-rows-per-poll=5)

My Requirement :- I need to pass a system variable to the node_id column and 5 ids select from select query to in condition

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter id="itemsInboundJdbcChannelAdapter"
        auto-startup="true" data-source="dataSource" channel="ItemsInboundJdbcChannel"
        query="SELECT QXXXX_ID,BXXXX_ID,TXXXX_ID,RXXXX_ID,EXXXXID,NODE_ID FROM XXXX_QXXXX WHERE XXXX_STATUS = :identier ORDER BY QXXXX_ID asc FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED"
        update="UPDATE XXXX_QXXXX SET XXXX_STATUS ='IT_PROCESSED',NODE_ID=(:NODE_ID),UPDATE_BY='BISWO',UPDATED_ON=SYSDATE WHERE QXXXX_ID IN (:QXXXX_ID)"
        row-mapper="xxDataRowMapper" max-rows-per-poll="${item.transfer.jdbc.max.rows}"
        select-sql-parameter-source="myItemsSelectSqlParameterSource"
        update-sql-parameter-source-factory="myUpdateParameterSource">
        <int:poller id="jdbcPoller" fixed-delay="${item.transfer.poller.jdbc.fixed.delay}" task-executor="notificationExecutor"  error-channel="chainToFailedOut">
            <int:transactional transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
        </int:poller>
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:service-activator input-channel="ItemsInboundJdbcChannel"
        ref="getMyService" >
        <int:poller fixed-delay="${item.transfer.poller.jdbc.fixed.delay}" />
    </int:service-activator>
```

```
<bean id="myUpdateParameterSource"
        class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory">
        <property name="parameterExpressions">
            <map>
                <entry key="NODE_ID" value=" #this['nodeId']"/>
                <entry key="QXXXX_ID" value="#this['qxxxxId']" />
            </map>
        </property>
</bean>
```

**xxxDataRowMapper.java**

```
@Override
public XXXDataModel mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
    XXDataModel object=null;
    if(rs!=null){
     long queueId=rs.getLong("QXXXX_ID");
     long batchId=rs.getLong("BXXXX_ID");
     long tradeRunId=rs.getLong("TXXXX_ID");
     long riskRunId=rs.getLong("RXXXX_RUN_ID");
    long eventId=rs.getLong("EXXXXID");
      object=new XXDataModel(queueId,batchId,tradeRunId,riskRunId,eventId,this.nodeId);
    }
    return object;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the question is not clear. What you have tried to do and what didn't work for you. What you have so far with the `SELECT` and `UPDATE` statements looks good so far... Fully not sure what is that `node_id` if you get it from the `SELECT` and what the `5 ids` are you talking about?..

Comment: Node_id is intially  empty I am setting it in rowmapper.

Comment: @Bilan I want to pass one additional value to update an additional column  which is not part of select statement and it's a static value.In this case a system variable.

Comment: So, maybe you need to do that conditionally in the mapper? Why do you mention a system property then ?

Comment: Still not clear... do you know what is `@Value` and how it can be used to resolve properties placeholders? And it does it against system properties as well! https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-beandef-annotation-based

Comment: Since I set max-row-per-poll is 5 I am getting 5 IDs. So I am getting  an jdbc error because in place of node-id it is passing 5 ? Marks in preparestatement

Comment: Huh? `update-per-row = "true"` ? https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-inbound-channel-adapter

Comment: @Bilan ,I am avoiding 'update-per-row = "true"' .Because 5 time it will going to run update statement in my case. Is there a way ,I can pass a system variable to the update query? Since I have multi node application ,I want to store the node id which has picked the one set of result.

Comment: See in this case <int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter query="select * from item where status=2"
    channel="target" data-source="dataSource"
    update="update item set status=10 where id in (:id)" /> 10 has been hard coded.I want that 10 needs to come from system variable.

Comment: Does this work for you `status=${status.property.from.system}` ?

Comment: Let me try out.I will update you soon.if it works I will update and close the question.

Comment: If it works, I'll convert a comment to the answer and will encourage to accept it because other people in the community might be interested in the same solution. This way we help them and I won't need to re-answer the same question again, Thanks for understading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply can go the same `properties placeholder` way and do something like this:

```
update="UPDATE XXXX_QXXXX SET XXXX_STATUS ='IT_PROCESSED',NODE_ID='${node_id.from-system.properties}', UPDATE_BY='BISWO',UPDATED_ON=SYSDATE WHERE QXXXX_ID IN (:QXXXX_ID)"
```

Spring will understand your PP pattern, resolves it against an `Environment` and the final value will be present in the target SQL statement to use.

Comment: @Artrem  Its works for me with this 'UPDATE XXXX_QXXXX SET XXXX_STATUS ='IT_PROCESSED',NODE_ID='${nodeId}',UPDATE_BY='BISWO',UPDATED_ON=SYSDATE WHERE QXXXX_ID IN (:QXXXX_ID)'

Comment: From Debug result UPDATE XXXX_QXXXX SET XXXX_STATUS ='IT_PROCESSED',NODE_ID='biswoTest123',UPDATE_BY='BISWO',UPDATED_ON=SYSDATE WHERE QXXXX_ID IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: Ah, yes. If it is a string it has to be wrapped to quotes. Updated an answer. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Right, just leave it as you have. We need to honor Oracle requirements.